# match a double quoted-string with double-quote inside

Tags: python, regex, double-quotes

I have this python string:

```
string = '"/dev/null" "" "19/1333329478.9381399" 0 1 "cam-foo" 64 900.0 "Foo x rev scan of test" "/usr/bin/env ""PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH"" python app.py" 60.145855 2.034689'
```

I need a regex that gives me a list of every element in this string.
Element: any number or any string contained in a double quote. A string can contain a double quote.

I've come out with this regex:

```
import re    
p = re.compile(r'"[^"]*"|[-\.\d]+')
p.findall(string)
['"/dev/null"', '""', '"19/1333329478.9381399"', '0', '1', '"cam-foo"', '64', '900.0', '"Foo x rev scan of test"', '"/usr/bin/env "', '"PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH"', '" python app.py"', '60.145855', '2.034689']
```

As you can see I miss the part of double-quote inside the string. **Double-quote inside an element should be ignored.** I'd like to have this result:

```
['"/dev/null"', '""', '"19/1333329478.9381399"', '0', '1', '"cam-foo"', '64', '900.0', '"Foo x rev scan of test"', '"/usr/bin/env ""PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH"" python app.py"', '60.145855', '2.034689']
```

Instead to have 3 (or more) elements

```
[..., '"/usr/bin/env "', '"PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH"', '" python app.py"', ...]
```

I'd like to have only one element:

```
'"/usr/bin/env ""PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH"" python app.py"'
```

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/library/csv).

#### [Example](http://ideone.com/W0nRq)

```
>>> import csv
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(list(csv.reader([string], delimiter=' ', quotechar='"')))
[
[
'/dev/null'
,
''
,
'19/1333329478.9381399'
,
'0'
,
'1'
,
'cam-foo'
,
'64'
,
'900.0'
,
'Foo x rev scan of test'
,
'/usr/bin/env "PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH" python app.py'
,
'60.145855'
,
'2.034689'
]
]
```

Comment: That's actually a pretty clever use of the `csv` module. I commend you!

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution! Yes, I agree with @jathanism
I think to adopt this solution for my problem. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

The first half of your regular expression currently matches a pair of double quotes surrounding zero or more non-double-quote characters.

```
r'"[^"]*"'
```

You can achieve your desired result by changing which strings you match inside the surrounding double quotes.

```
r'"(?:[^"]|"")*"'
```

This regular expression matches a pair of double quotes that surround zero or more strings; each string must consist of either one non-double-quote character or two consecutive double quotes. (The `?:` marks the parenthesized bit as a non-capturing group; otherwise Python will only return the bit inside the parentheses.)

Let's plug that into your complete regex:

```
% python
Python 2.7.2 (default, Mar 20 2012, 13:27:18) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 3.1 (tags/Apple/clang-318.0.54)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import re
>>> s = '"/dev/null" "" "19/1333329478.9381399" 0 1 "cam-foo" 64 900.0 "Foo x rev scan of test" "/usr/bin/env ""PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH"" python app.py" 60.145855 2.034689'
>>> for el in re.findall(r'"(?:[^"]|"")*"|[-\.\d]+', s): print(el)
... 
"/dev/null"
""
"19/1333329478.9381399"
0
1
"cam-foo"
64
900.0
"Foo x rev scan of test"
"/usr/bin/env ""PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH"" python app.py"
60.145855
2.034689
>>>
```

Comment: This regex works like a charm. In a first moment I thought to adopt this solution, but in practice I've chosen @j-f-sebastian's solution (with cvs module). Your solution and csv solution give me the same result and they parse the log in the same way, but the list that I have with csv is "cleaner" than the list of this solution (all the strings don't have the double quote inside the string itself)
Thanks again for your effort, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is to be able to split this exact case, you can use [`shlex.split()`](http://docs.python.org/library/shlex.html#shlex.split):

```
>>> import shlex
>>> s = '"/dev/null" "" "19/1333329478.9381399" 0 1 "cam-foo" 64 900.0 "Foo x rev scan of test" "/usr/bin/env ""PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH"" python app.py" 60.145855 2.034689'
>>> shlex.split(s)
['/dev/null', '', '19/1333329478.9381399', '0', '1', 'cam-foo', '64', '900.0', 'Foo x rev scan of test', '/usr/bin/env PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH python app.py', '60.145855', '2.034689']
>>> shlex.split(s)[-3]
'/usr/bin/env PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH python app.py'
```

It's not regex, but it will solve this exact problem for you every time.

Comment: Completely dropping `'"'`around `PATH=..` might be incorrect.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help but unfortunately I can't use shlex for two reasons: as J.F. Sebastian said, it drops '"' in the string.
The other reason is performance: I have a largefile and it's very very slow.

Comment: Fair enough, I hadn't considered the dropped double quotes when I suggested this.

Answer (score 0):

Enclose the regex search token in (). 
What happens is, re will nor return a list for each find. 
Pick the right array element.
E.g.:

```
m = p.findall(string)
```

Will return a list in m, whose each element is again a tokenised list according to what was enclosed in your (). 
This way you can retrieve the exact part of the statement that you desire.

Comment: So do you mean: p = re.compile(r'("[^"]*"|[-\.\d]+)'). If yes, I've already tried and the result is the same.